# Which is the most efficient DataSet query operation?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, linq

Is it more efficient to create a query this way:

```
var ordersDataTable = dataSet.Tables["Orders"];

var query = ordersDataTable.Select("OrderType = '" + orderType + "' AND Status = 'ACT'");
```

Or using Linq, like this:

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> query =
    from order in dataSet.Tables["Orders"].AsEnumerable()
    where (order.Field<string>("OrderType") == "'" + orderType + "'") &&
          (order.Field<string>("Status") == "'ACT'")
    select order;
```

If you are then going to process the rows returned like this:

```
foreach (var p in query)
{...}
```

The question came about when the filter gets applied (all at once or creating a "generator" and whether the order.Field("OrderType") constructions get re-evaluated every time as you iterate.

The data comes from an XML file loaded into a DataSet object.

Comment: _... if you have two horses and want to know which is faster... run them_ Wait what do you mean for _efficient_ ?

Comment: AsEnumerable will retrieve all the rows on the table

Comment: Will ordersDataTable.Select do the same? If all rows are retrieved, they will be filtered, right?

Answer (score 2):

The LINQ approach will evaluate `order.Field<string>("OrderType")` for each iteration, including ones that correspond to rows not appearing in the result. In addition, it will evaluate `order.Field<string>("Status")` for each row with matching order type. This behavior is hard to optimize out, because the `order` parameter is different in each iteration. You can speed up the processing a little by using the overload which takes `DataColumn`:

```
var ordTypeCol = ordersDataTable.Columns["OrderType"];
var ordStatusCol = ordersDataTable.Columns["Status"];
var query =
    from order in dataSet.Tables["Orders"].AsEnumerable()
    where (order.Field<string>(ordTypeCol) == orderType) &&
          (order.Field<string>(ordStatusCol) == "ACT")
    select order;
```

**Note:** Concatenation expression below

```
"'" + orderType + "'"
```

would be evaluated in each iteration as well. This, however, can be optimized by creating a variable outside the `where` clause. Good chances are that this concatenation is unnecessary, though, because LINQ version does not parse your literals, so it does not need quotes around values (thanks, [Ivan Stoev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5202563/ivan-stoev), for a comment).

Comment: Just to note that concatenation (and `'` surrounding the "ACT") in LINQ version is a bug.

Comment: @IvanStoev Yes, the two versions are mutually exclusive: assuming that the first version works, the second version has a bug, and vice versa.

Comment: It's worth noting that this solution introduces two closures, meaning that the references `ordTypeCol` and `ordStatusCol` will be promoted to the heap.  You may see different memory management behavior in certain cases-- this could be a concern if the data table is very large, since it cannot be garbage collected until those closures are garbage collected too.

Comment: @JohnWu the original one also closed over orderType variable, so the closure would be in a heap anyway, right?

Comment: The variable `orderType` does not contain an internal reference to the DataTable or the DataStorage instance behind it, so it shouldn't affect its GC.

Answer (score 1):

Both techniques will result in a "table scan" of the memory structure containing the data that were extracted from the XML.  So in terms of pure query efficiency, they should be very close.

However, using the DataTable.Select method requires the framework to parse the string that is passed in.  This will probably add a small amount of overhead.  Also, it is more problematic in terms of compile-time error detection, since the expression won't be parsed until run-time.  Using the Linq method ensures strong type checking and fewer runtime issues.

Also, using the Linq method, you don't have to concatenate (or escape) for syntax, e.g. you don't need to use `"'" + myString + "'"`, you can just use `myString`.  Not only is this easier to type and read, but it can protect against [injection attacks](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Code_Injection).

Comment: LINQ version against `DataRow` is not typesafe either, because of the `string` field names and hard coded `type` arguments to `Field<>` calls. The only safer is the comparison operators and constants.

Comment: So, for example, `order.Field<int>("ID") == "test")` will not compile, and `order.Field<string>("Name") == 123` will not compile.  You are correct there is no compile-time checking of `<type>` against the type stored in `DataTable.Columns[name].DataType`, since the column definitions can be changed at run time.